# How to create a toolbar (or something similar) with centered and correctly spread items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

i'm new to android developing, i've been search for two days a way to equally spread items on a toolbar like this:
http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/instagram-android.jpg

Some people say to use a custom layout, some say using custom layout is not advisable.
Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TabLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

And also you can add ViewPager to slide tabs and screen by swiping horizontally
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html